# How to delete several none sequential lines in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file over 1000000 lines and i need to remove 200000 lines.
I have the line numbers.
Is there a fast way of doing it rather than doing it one by one?

Comment: what format are your line numbers stored in? i.e. an array, a text file, etc..?

Comment: Do you mean "non-sequential"?

Comment: What criteria tell you which lines should be removed?  You could program a macro but you'd need to tell it what to look for to determine which lines to delete.

Comment: I'd assume you'll need some external scripting language with regular expression support.  Or at least something that can suck them into an array and be aware of the line numbers that need to go.

Comment: Are they just blank lines between every "filled" line?  That's easy to do with find-replace.  @kiss-o-matic Notepad++ has regex support, so if regex is needed, Notepad++ has it.

Comment: Its a txt file. by non sequential I mean they are not in a row or grouped together.